# Contar vogais e saber quantas há

Tags: python-3.x, contador

Boas!
Queria criar uma função que me permitisse dizer se uma palavra ou frase tem vogais, e se sim, quantas vogais tem, mas tenho 2 problemas no meu código que não entendo:

```
def conta_vogais(str):
    vogais = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    if str.lower() in vogais:
        return True
        vogais.count('a','e','i','o','u')
    else:
        return False
```

Quando corro o programa, ele parece não aceitar mais do que uma letra para correr o if statement e qd ponho só uma letra tb n me diz o valor da contagem.
Será que alguém me consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Existe uma classe no Python chamada [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Com ela você consegue fazer isso de maneira eficiente e sem reinventar a roda.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
def vogais(string):
    return Counter(re.sub('[^aeiouAEIOU]', '', string))
```

Comment: @Miguel O `Counter` aceita um 'iterable-or-mapping' e uma string no Python é 'iterable'. Tipo `for c in 'teste': print(c)`.

Comment: Sem problemas, @Miguel. Isso mostra como muitas vezes um código "perspicaz", como disse, não é tão bom assim pra ser mantido. Acaba ficando confuso tudo numa linha e não fica claro o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @Miguel mas ai você saberia o total de todas as vogais, não a quantidade de cada. Sobre o segundo comentário, concordo totalmente. Editei o código.

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer assim:

**1.**

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    result = {}
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    for i in vogais:
        if i in string:
            result[i] = string.count(i)
    return result

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

Ou fazendo com *[dictinary compreension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)* basta::

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    return {i: string.count(i) for i in vogais if i in string}

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

Output:

> {'a': 3, 'o': 1}

**2.**

Fiz o exemplo acima de maneira a que contasse e retornasse o numero de vezes que aparece, e só caso apareça. Mas se quiseres simplesmente o total de vogais podes:

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    result = 0
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    for i in vogais:
        result += string.count(i)
    return result

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

OU:

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    return sum(string.count(i) for i in vogais)

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

Que vai dar, neste caso `4`

**3.**

Já agora, para completar mais um pouco a resposta, também podes retornar o número de vezes que aparece cada uma (as que não aparecem inclusive):

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    result = {}
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    for i in vogais:
        result[i] = string.count(i)
    return result

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

Ou fazendo com *[dictinary compreension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)* basta:

```
def conta_vogais(string):
    string = string.lower() # para que a comparação não seja sensível a maiuscula/minuscula
    vogais = 'aeiou'
    return {i: string.count(i) for i in vogais}

print(conta_vogais('olaaa'))
```

Output:

> {'a': 3, 'e': 0, 'u': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 1}

Comment: Thanks!! Ajudas-te me imenso :)

Comment: Sê bem vindo ao stack overflow PT @MiguelLuís