# Contar vogais e armazenar em dicionário

Tags: python

Li [essa pergunta e suas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166519/contar-vogais-e-saber-quantas-h%C3%A1) mas ainda tenho uma dúvida.

Queria uma função que contasse a quantidade de vogais em um texto e armazenasse em um dicionário onde a chave é a vogal considerada.

Comment: A pergunta que você citou já faz isso, não? Basta entender as respostas dadas. Se não, descreva qual é exatamente o problema.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas lá resolveu? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166519/3635 Testou a solução da Michele e do Miguel?

Answer (score -3):

```
word = "tal coisa tal"
Delimitador = "aeiou"
k = 0
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] in Delimitador:
        k++
```

Comment: Perdão, não entendi. Se quiser colocar um código em Python, selecione a parte desejada e aperte `ctrl+k`