# como CONTAR VALORES atribuídos a VOGAIS, se estas VOGAIS estiverem presentes em uma PALAVRA ou TEXTO?

Tags: python-3.x

Primeiramente, minha dúvida é justamente em como montar a estrutura dos dados (VOGAIS e  VALORES), ou seja, qual a melhor forma montar os dados "vogais" e seus respectivos "valores"? Ou ainda, qual estrutura usar? (lista, dicionario, tupla,....)

Em segundo, como contar os valores numéricos atribuídos às vogais, caso a palavra digitada contenha as vogais?

Neste link ([Contar vogais e saber quantas há](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166519/contar-vogais-e-saber-quantas-h%c3%a1)) como sugerido pelo colega na versão anterior da minha pergunta, mostra como contar as vogais, porém, neste caso que proponho, as vogais não necessariamente precisam ser contadas, mas só identificadas/lidas na palavra digitada, e o seu valor somado com as demais que estiverem presentes, não importando se a vogal for repetida ou não.

Assim, a vogais terão valores, por exemplo:

## cada vogal tem um valor atribuído

```
vogais = ['a' = 1,  'e' = 2, 'i' = 3, 'o' = 4, 'u' = 5]
```

## obs:(não sei como montar essa estrutura de correspondência entre as vogais e os valores: uma lista de vogais e outra de números? um dicionário? tupla? apenas variáveis comuns?

## inserindo a palavra

```
palavras = input("digite uma palavra:" )
```

Vamos supor que seja digitada a palavra "biblioteca"

Então seria algo assim:

```
Leia cada vogal da palavra: #devo usar list()?
valor da vogal = 0
Se vogal estiver em palavra:
    valor da vogal + valor da vogal
senão:
    print(valor da vogal)
```

## alguém poderia me sugerir algum material que ensine a esquematizar os dados de forma que eles fiquem aptos a serem manipulados? Estou estudando algoritimos, mas não encontrei nada que ensine a criar as variáveis com dados em estruturas mais "complexas".

Comment: Você pode fazer assim: `saida = [vogais[c] for c in palavras if c in vogais]` e se fizer: `print(saida)` terá o resultado: `[3, 1]` e para somar: `print(sum(saida))` terá o resultado: `4`

Comment: Entendi o que você sugeriu, mas não deu certo, provavelmente por causa da minha variável VOGAIS, não sei como montar essa estrutura de string receber um valor inteiro, vou editar a pergunta novamente especificando melhor. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Não deu certo porque esta errado, em vez de `vogais = ['a' = 1,  'e' = 2, 'i' = 3, 'o' = 4, 'u' = 5]` tem que ser dicionário `vogais = { 'a': 1, 'e': 2, 'i': 3, 'o': 4, 'u': 5 }`

Comment: Muito obrigado NoobSaibot!!!!